# Uniform Continuity of $\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

I want to show $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty)$. I know it is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and I can show it's uniformly cts. on $[1, \infty)$, so if I choose $x=1/2$ and $y\in [1,\infty)$, is it uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: What you wrote is a series of statements with no connection between them. A mathematical proof this is not. Also, you cannot just "choose" $x$. What you need to prove is the statement: "For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$." You did not prove this statement.

Comment: I'm asking about the idea of the proof, not the details

Comment: I understand that. But in order to discuss what you already did, you need to write that in a coherent manner, not by simply throwing some symbols around.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $$|\sqrt{|x|} -\sqrt{|y|} |\leqslant \sqrt{|x-y|}$$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R} .$